# Save and Load testing classify Naive Bayes Classifier in NLTK in another method

Tags: python, classification, nltk

I have try the code from here: [Save Naive Bayes Trained Classifier in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017086/save-naive-bayes-trained-classifier-in-nltk).
I want to classify tweet into positive class or negative class.
this is my code:

```
#learning.py
def main_learning():
   .......
   classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(feature_set)
   save_classifier(classifier)

   classifier2 = load_classifier()
   print classifier2.classify(get_features("My tweet is bad".split())

def save_classifier(classifier):
   f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
   pickle.dump(classifier, f)
   f.close()

def load_classifier():
   f = with open('my_classifier.pickle')
   classifier = pickle.load(f)
   f.close
   return classifier
```

Then the output: `negative`

But, when I try the `save_classifier` and `load_classifier` in different method, the output become always positive class.

this is the code:

```
#learning.py
def main_learning():
   .......
   classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(feature_set)
   save_classifier(classifier)

def test_classify():
   classifier = load_classifier()
   print classifier.classify(get_features("My tweet is bad".split())

the def save_classifier and load_classifier() are same with the first ones.
```

The second output is: `positive`.
It should be still `negative` class.

What happen with my code??
Thanks

Edit:

From the answer from @Cassio then I edit my code:

```
def save_classifier(classifier):
       f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
       pickle.dump(classifier, f)
       f.close()

def load_classifier():
   f = with open('my_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
   classifier = pickle.load(f)
   f.close
   return classifier
```

Actually it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the environment setup to test out your code, but I have the feeling it's not right in the part where you save/load the pickle.

Referring to the [Storing Taggers](http://nltk.org/book/ch05.html) section of the NLTK book, I would change your code and do it like this:

```
def save_classifier(classifier):
   f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
   pickle.dump(classifier, f, -1)
   f.close()

def load_classifier():
   f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
   classifier = pickle.load(f)
   f.close()
   return classifier
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but the parameter `-1` at `pickle.dump(classifier, f, -1)` in `def save_classifier` return an error, so I make it without parameter (default is 0).

Comment: @FahmiRizal: Did you manage to get it working? If so, can you please confirm the answer?

Comment: The [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) say the new syntax is `pickle.dump(classifier, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`. [The problem might have been the defaultdict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020823/pickling-a-trained-nltk-model#comment29674121_13020823).